# How to handle In-app purchase subscriptions? and how can I get the receipts of it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have searched a lot for sample codes of subscriptions but no one has explained about receipts and manage subscriptions programmatically. I would like to know about working of in-app purchase subscriptions. Anyone has any sample code for subscriptions handling and receipt generations? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check below url...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation